# How to inject Ionic Geolocation in karma tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I'm doing my first non-hello-world app with ionic/angular.

I've created one page(`map.page.ts`), which uses the Geolocation to center a map on the correct spot.
When I execute it, it works fine, but if I try to run the test, even the default one:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MapPage } from './map.page';

describe('MapPage', () => {
  let component: MapPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MapPage>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MapPage ],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MapPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

fails with this error:

```
Failed: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Geolocation -> Geolocation]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Geolocation!
```

Here is my map.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.page.scss'],
})
export class MapPage implements OnInit {
  lat: number = 46.204391;
  lng: number = 6.143158;
  zoom: number = 15;

  constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.geolocation
      .getCurrentPosition()
      .then((resp) => {
        this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
      });
  }
}
```

And the Geolocation is declared in the map.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MapPageRoutingModule } from './map-routing.module';

import { MapPage } from './map.page';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { AgmJsMarkerClustererModule } from '@agm/js-marker-clusterer';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    MapPageRoutingModule,
    AgmJsMarkerClustererModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment.googleMapsAPIKey,
    }),
  ],
  declarations: [MapPage],
  providers: [Geolocation],
})
export class MapPageModule {}
```

Why is karma not able to load this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It belongs to `MapPageModule` which wasn't imported into `TestBed`. Because it's part of the same Component you're testing you can specify it separately in `providers` section.

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MapPage } from './map.page';

describe('MapPage', () => {
  let component: MapPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MapPage>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const geolocation = {
      getCurrentPosition: new Subject(),
    };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MapPage ],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        Geolocation, // <-- here, but better to mock.
//      {
//        providers: Geolocation,
//        useValue: geolocation,
//      },
      ],

    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MapPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: make sense, I'm not familiar with karma, I've to find some courses on this :)
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: karma is just a test runner in browsers, it's better to find course for angular testing and learn jasmine: https://angular.io/guide/testing and https://jasmine.github.io

Comment: Totally agree :) My undestranding is that one does unit tests and the other one more integration tests?